# Does working in Saudi Arabia with German nationality require paying taxes to Germany?

Tags: taxes, salary, tax-treaties

For a German citizen who is working in the Saudi Arabia (Saudi company with Saudi contract), is it required to report income taxes every year in Germany?

Comment: Other facts might be relevant. I haven't read it but I expect the details to be covered in https://www.bundesfinanzministerium.de/Web/DE/Themen/Steuern/Internationales_Steuerrecht/Staatenbezogene_Informationen/Saudi_Arabien/saudi_arabien.html

Answer (score 3):

In almost every country (exception USA) it is residents paying income tax. Living in Saudi Arabia you are not a German tax resident and don’t pay income tax in Germany.

Only thing is that Germany wants to know about foreign income to calculate the tax rate on German income correctly.